# "Oбобщенно народный" или "обобщенно-народный"?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Как пишется обобщенно народный?

Думаю, что пишется раздельно. Но если это наречие и прилагательное, то вопрос как?, кажется, странно задавать: народный (как?) обобщенно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше выбрать вариант: **обобщенно-народный.**

Так пишутся сложные прилагательные, составленные из основ двух прилагательных, например:

**обобщенный народный образ — обобщенно- народный образ.**

**Примечание.** Отношения между прилагательными могут быть как однородные, таки неоднородные.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49

9. Пишутся через дефис многие сложные прилагательные, части которых указывают на неоднородные признаки:

Военно-медицинская академия (ср. Военная медицинская академия)

добровольно-спортивные общества (ср. добровольные спортивные общества)

народно-освободительное движение (ср. народное освободительное движение)